# How to implement a multi-step wizard in RxJava way?

Tags: rx-java

I was trying to implement some multi-step usage wizard in RxJava. To simplify the case, let's suppose users can only go to the next step but not backward.

I was thinking to model each step as an observable which will render itself when subscribed and will complete itself when the user select to go to next step. So there will be step1_Observable, step2_Observable, etc.

Then the logic of the wizard controller would go like
1) subscribe to step1_Observable
2) when step1_Observable completes, subscribe to step2_Observable
3) when step2_Observable completes, subscribe to step3_Observable
so on and so forth.

One might think why couldn't I just model the next step button click event as an observable and subscribe to it to render the next step. The reason is, in my design, each step will have it's own unique method for user to navigate to next page. For example, it might be specific gesture on the touch screen, or even answer a quiz correctly.

I could not figure how I can achieve this with the operations provided by Rx. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

`flatMap` is used to run `Observable`s in order. Here is an example to show how to run an Observable after some Observable completes:

```
public Observable<String> step1() {
    return null;
}

public Observable<String> step2() {
    return null;
}

public Observable<String> step3() {
    return null;
}

public Observable<String> chainSteps(final Observable<String> first, final Observable<String> second) {
    return first.flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<String>>() {

        @Override
        public Observable<String> call(String s) {
            return Observable.empty();
        }
    }, new Func1<Throwable, Observable<String>>() {

        @Override
        public Observable<String> call(Throwable e) {
            return Observable.error(e);
        }
    }, new Func0<Observable<String>>() {

        @Override
        public Observable<String> call() {
            return second;
        }
    });
}

public void example() {
    chainSteps(chainSteps(step1(), step2()), step3()).subscribe(...);
}
```

You can also use `Transformer` to make the codes more reusable.

```
public class ChainTransformer<T> implements Observable.Transformer<T, T> {

    private final Observable<T> other;

    public ChainTransformer(Observable<T> other) {
        this.other = other;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<? extends T> call(Observable<? extends T> observable) {
        return observable.flatMap(new Func1<T, Observable<T>>() {

            @Override
            public Observable<T> call(T s) {
                return Observable.empty();
            }
        }, new Func1<Throwable, Observable<T>>() {

            @Override
            public Observable<T> call(Throwable e) {
                return Observable.error(e);
            }
        }, new Func0<Observable<T>>() {

            @Override
            public Observable<T> call() {
                return other;
            }
        });
    }
}

public void example() {
    step1().compose(new ChainTransformer<String>(step2()))
            .compose(new ChainTransformer<String>(step3()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I didn't know there is a variation of flatMap which allow to return a new observable in onComplete callback. Glad to learn this tip. There is just one thing I don't particularly like in your solution - we have to nest the chainSteps call. If will be clumsy when we have more steps than 3.Not sure whether there is a better solution.

Comment: I updated the answer. You can use `compose` and `Transformer` to make the code cleaner.